# Does iOS support wildcards for associated domains? (*.company.com)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, info.plist, wildcard-subdomain, associated-domains

I need to create a solution that has a URL in the format of GUID.company.com.  The GUID is customer supplied and redirects to a client-hosted instance of the product.

The idea is that a client can host their instance either at our facility, or at their own, with zero downtime of either.  In addition, this will allow the customer to fine-tune which version of the app they would like to auto-launch via a URL link.  (accomplished through editing the `./.well-known` files)

Here are the deployment options I'd like to offer my customers

```
https://guid1.company.com -> 301 redirect to multitenant hosted -> launch app if installed

https://guid2.company.com -> 301 redirect to client-hosted -> launch app if installed

https://guid3.company.com -> cloud flare redirect logic -> launch app if installed
```

**Question**

My question for iOS people (and will have the same question for android) is such a solution possible?

Answer (score 1):

To support universal links in your app, take the following steps:

- Add an entitlement that specifies the domains your app supports.
- Update your app delegate to respond appropriately when it receives
  the NSUserActivity object.

for more information you can access the link [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)